# How to handle 2 asp.net identity authentications so that when logged in to one does not log out from another?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have 2 asp.net identity authentications for backend users and site users  When I log in to both, the first authentication gets logged out.How to handle 2 asp.net identity authentications so that when logged in to one does not log out from another?